# Handle Response code that contains no Description in Swagger

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, http-error, http-response-codes

In Swagger After Executing a Request.
The Server Response for Errors Doesn't Contain Accurate Description(Bad Request) of the Error
Instead it Shows Only the Status code( Error: response status is 400).

[Current Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53A8w.png)

Upon Inspection of Network Tab the Response Status Code Also Doesn't Contain Status Code Description

Using .NetCore API 3.1
And Swashbuckle Aspnetcore -6.4.0

Statup.cs

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "BAIM");
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Action Method in Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

[Required Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIIy3.png)

Need the Response With Error Description.
Upon Removing '''app.UseHttpsRedirection();''' From startup.cs Response is in the Required Format But using http is  not Practical.
Reason Why this is Happening is Also Unknown.
If there is way to Customize Error: That is Also Good

I have Tried :

- Reinstalling Packages
- Removed Exception Handling Middleware Swagger Documentation And
  Configuration, Authentication To Check If Its Working For Now .
- Tried Sending Only Response Code Only.
- Writing Response Instead of Returning Bad Request

Thank a Lot in Advance

Comment: Hi @NotYetGrounded, your code just return the status code 400, of course the response only contains the status code, it works as expected. What's the result you want get?

Comment: Hello Rena, I'm getting the output as shown in first image link,
I want my out to be same as the second image .

Comment: Hi @Rena, I returned status code 400 for testing . I updated it now please look into it.
Thank you